# Can you get metrics and statistics from Hibernate OGM?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to get performance data from Hibernate OGM.  It doesn't seem to have the Hibernate statistics classes like Hibernate ORM.   Is there something equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

The reason there are not specific classes is that you should be able to use the existing one in ORM.

For example:

```
org.hibernate.stat.Statistics statistics = getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
statistics.setStatisticsEnabled( true );
final Session session = openSession();
...
statistics.logSummary();
session.close();
```

If you think that something is missing or not working, you can signal it on the Hibernate OGM [Jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/OGM/summary) or [forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewforum.php?f=31).

Davide